# parallel changin region - WIND_OVERRIDE

Tags: grass-gis, masking, parallel-processing, regionalization

INTRODUCTION: I have 5000 mammal species and I'm studying Extreme Climate Event impacts on them. I'm now analysing warm spell duration index (WSDI) which is defined as number of days in a year where Temp>90th percentile of the historical (1961-1990 in my case). I'm modifying the index calculating the 90th percentile of the historical within the range of the species, and not limited to the "temporal evolution" of the single cell, so that I have for every mammal a WSDI which is proper to that mammal.

PROBLEM : The whole problem of WSDI modification works, and it is not the topic of this question. The problem is that it takes really long time (1 month). I was suggested to use parallel, running at the same time 10x500 (or even less) instead of 5000 species all togheter. The problem is that for the process of modification I have to change region at every step, at every species, using also r.mask to calculate 90th percentile within range. Changing region during parallel seems not possible from the guide here: https://grasswiki.osgeo.org/wiki/Parallel_GRASS_jobs.

QUESTION: Is there a way to avoid that? I read on  the guide that something similar is possible saving the region at every time using WIND_OVERRIDE, is that exact? Otherwise, I maybe can use only r.mask without using g.region, so that the problem does not appear?

Comment: Can I ask to fill in some details: What type of data do you have- raster or vector? Can you provide the current region settings. What is the command you are running that takes 1 month?

Comment: The easiest approach is to let each job run in its own mapset. You can generate them on the fly in a loop with `g.mapset` (https://grass.osgeo.org/grass-stable/manuals/g.mapset.html).

Comment: markusN you mean without using parallel? Or with the help of it?